# how to build aggregate in ddd, passing VO or raw data?

Tags: domain-driven-design

What is the correct way of designing aggregate in DDD, for exmaple you need to create some user, and to create it we need to have id, email, living address and born address.
So we can do it like this (I'll use PHP as it's my main language):

```
  class User {
     private function __construct(
         private UserId $id,
         private Email $email,
         private Address $livingAddress,
         private Address $bornAddress
     ) {}

     public static create(
          string $uuid, 
          string $email, 
          string $city, 
          string $country, 
          string $address,
          string $bornCity, 
          string $bornCountry, 
          string $bornAddress,
     ) {
        return new self (
            UsesId::fromString($uuid),
            new Email($email),
            new Address($city, $country, $address),
            new Address($bornCity, $bornCountry, $bornAddress)
        );
     }
  }
```

in this case we following a rule that aggregate root responsible of checking all invariants , because he creating all VO's and they has own validation. But it's adding complexity to actual `User` class, we have to many parameters passed etc.

Another possible solution is to build it like this:

```
  class User {
     private function __construct(
         private UserId $id,
         private Email $email,
         private Address $livingAddress,
         private Address $bornAddress
     ) {}

     public static create(
          UserId $id, 
          Email $email, 
          Address $livingAddress,
          Address $bornAddress
     ) {
        return new self (
            id,
            $email,
            $livingAddress,
            $bornAddress
        );
     }
  }
```

now `User` object is smaller, maybe even more "elegant", but we breaking the rule that aggregate should check all invariants.

And the third option is probably to use Factory, I'll not provide code here but explain how I see it. Basically factory takes a row data, create VO, and passing it to aggregate, so aggregate creation will look like in the second example. Again aggregate is not responsible for all invariants, but Factory is on one of allowed patterns by DDD so I think thats fine.

I know probably there is no a right way, but I want to hear some best practices and suggestions from someone who has distinct knowledge in DDD about how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

> we breaking the rule that aggregate should check all invariants.

I think you are misunderstanding this rule.

The aggregate is responsible for domain dynamics: how information changes over time.  In particular, it is responsible for ensuring that the information stored is internally consistent.

That's not the same problem as *input validation*, which as a rule we want to solve as close to the boundary as we can manage.

Imagine, if you will, a form submission that looks like

```
...&userId=alphabet-soup&...
```

Sure, "alphabet-soup" is a string, but it's not consistent with the schemas described in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), so something has gone Very Wrong, and we should be bailing out with a client error rather than forwarding the suspect data to the domain model.

See also [Parse, Don't Validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) (Alexis King, 2019)

Comment: well, I'm not telling about validation input, I agree that it should be done not in domain layer but still each VO or aggregate root also should take care of validation and very often those rules duplicated. For example we have `email`, I'll validate in in the controller, but also I'll validate if it's correct email in the domain, because we can't be sure it's covered by validation in outer layers